# Split Spark df row into equal lengths and reverse them to make columns

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to make equal length columns from a Spark df row? I have this row for instance.

```
100
149
177
102
133
149
16
19
19
```

Can I transform it this way? if n = 3

```
177 149 100
149 133 102
19  19  16
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by equal lengths? can you add example with few more data ? or you just want to add one more column ?

Comment: you want to transform each 2 rows to 2 cols?

Comment: spark version ??

Comment: Yes, the cut point will be in a variable n, and in this case, you can say its n = 2. and my spark version is 2.4.5

Comment: I have added solution, check below & let me know if its not working .. :)

Comment: is there any chances of having total row count like this 3,7,11,13 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code.

```
scala> val df = Seq(100,149,177,102,133,149,16,19,19).toDF("id")

scala> df.show(false)  
+---+                  
|id |                  
+---+                  
|100|                  
|149|                  
|177|                  
|102|                  
|133|                  
|149|                  
|16 |                  
|19 |                  
|19 |                  
+---+
```

```
scala> val n = 3
n: Int = 3
```

```
scala> val cutOff = df.count.toLong/n.toLong
cutOff: Long = 3
```

```
scala> val rowExpr = ntile(n.toInt).over(Window.orderBy(lit(1)))
```

```
scala> val columns = struct(
    (0L until cutOff)
    .map(i => col("data")(i).as(s"data_${i}"))
    .reverse:_*
)
```

```
scala> df
.withColumn("row_id",rowExpr)
.groupBy($"row_id")
.agg(collect_list($"id").as("data"))
.withColumn("data",columns)
.orderBy($"row_id".asc)
.select($"data.*")
.show(false)

+------+------+------+
|data_2|data_1|data_0|
+------+------+------+
|177   |149   |100   |
|149   |133   |102   |
|19    |19    |16    |
+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks again man, This is working fine but Can we generalize it?

Comment: can you kindly have a look at the question? I have modified it.

Comment: It is only giving the column

+------+
|data_0|
+------+
|100   |
|102   |
|16    |
+------+

Comment: Yes, Every single line and checked twice before commenting.

Comment: Let me just check again, I'm using databricks and there might be some cache issue. Let me restart the cluster and check again

Comment: Sorry that was my bad. It's working like a charm. Thanks again Srinivas

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `sliding` function from `mllib` to achieve this as below

Don't forget to add [spark-mllib](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib) dependency for this.

```
val df = Seq(100, 149, 177, 102, 133, 149, 16, 19, 19).toDF("id")

df.rdd.map(_.getInt(0))
  .sliding(3, 3)
  .map(vec => (vec(0), vec(1), vec(2)))
  .toDF("a", "b", "c")
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+
|a  |b  |c  |
+---+---+---+
|100|149|177|
|102|133|149|
|16 |19 |19 |
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I want rows in reverse order.
15 16
69 73

Comment: No its not like sorting. It has to be in that order.

Comment: I had wrong input so the output was on wrong order, check it now

Comment: It's not in the order, Can you mold it to this
```
+------+------+------+
|data_2|data_1|data_0|
+------+------+------+
|177   |149   |100   |
|149   |133   |102   |
|19    |19    |16    |
+------+------+------+
```

Comment: ComeOn, do you want us to do your all work?? Anyway, just change it to `.map(vec => (vec(2), vec(1), vec(0)))` or select on the order you want as after toDF add `.select ("c", "b", "a")`